# How to init several root provided services on app initialization in Angular 8?

Tags: angular8

I have several `initializable` services that implement this simple interface:

```
interface InitializableService {
   init(): void;
}
```

Those services make some global subscriptions (local and external) that I need during all the live of my app. What I do now is inject those services into my `app.component.ts` and call them one for one. I want to automate this process.

I have found some info about ways to do this and I just found ways to do it when providing the services into an module. I provide that services in `root` and I do not want to change this, besides the initial arrangement take the same time to just injecting them into `app.components.ts`.

I tried creating a base class and extend it so each class service that implement it would become "automatic initialized" on app load  but I wasn't able to get the list of services that extend that class to call init on them.

I have no idea where to start to achieve this, or if this is even possible with `provideIn: 'root'` services.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use Modules with providers ?

solution is , to create a module , something like core.module.ts

then import the module into app.module.ts.

The key is , inside of core module , using module with providers , you can initial the those useful services.

Using provide in root , I just don't like it

## core.module.ts Will be something like this

```
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { UsersData } from './data/users';
import { UsersService } from './mock/users.service';

const DATA_SERVICES = [
  { provide: UsersData, useClass: UsersService },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  providers: []
})
export class CoreModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: CoreModule,
      providers: [
        ...DATA_SERVICES,
      ]
    } as ModuleWithProviders;
  }
}
```